# Yeoman: Call Sub-Generator With User-Supplied Arguments

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm writing my first Yeoman generator, which prompts the user for various inputs and conditionally creates files based on their responses.  I need to be able to call a subroutine (could be a Yeoman sub-generator) based on user input, and pass arguments to it.

The reason I want to use named functions (which are not automatically run) is that sometimes the user's response should invoke a number of functions combined, and sometimes the function should be run alone.

**What I have tried:**

I figured sub-generators were the way to go, since I'm creating sets of files only if the user requests them. But I'm having trouble calling them *conditionally* and passing them the user-supplied input.  I've tried using `hookFor`, but I get the assertion error: `hookFor must be used within the constructor only`.  (Because I don't want it to be run by default, I'm calling the sub-generator from my `this.prompt(prompts, function (props)`).

**The question:**

How do I call a routine only if the user requests it (via a prompt), and pass that routine some user-supplied information?

If you're kind enough to answer, please don't assume that I've tried something obvious ;-).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Let's consider you have a generator `generator-blog` (BlogGenerator) with two sub generators (blog-server and blog-client):

```
app\index.js
client\index.js
server\index.js
```

So when you run `yo blog` you what to ask the user for some options and run (optionally) sub generators, right?

To run a subgenerator you need to call `this.invoke("generator_namespace", {options: {}})`.
The second argument we passed can have `options` field - it's options object which will be passed to the generator.

In app\index.js:

```
BlogGenerator.prototype.askFor = function askFor() {
  var cb = this.async();

  // have Yeoman greet the user.
  console.log(this.yeoman);

  var prompts = [{
    name: 'appName',
    message: 'Enter your app name',
    default: 'MyBlog'
  }, {
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'createServer',
    message: 'Would you like to create server project?',
    default: true
  }, {
    type: 'confirm',
    name: 'createClient',
    message: 'Whould you like to create client project?',
    default: true
  }];

  this.prompt(prompts, function (props) {
    this.appName = props.appName;
    this.createServer = props.createServer;
    this.createClient = props.createClient;

    cb();
  }.bind(this));
}

BlogGenerator.prototype.main = function app() {
  if (this.createClient) {
    // Here: we'are calling the nested generator (via 'invoke' with options)
    this.invoke("blog:client", {options: {nested: true, appName: this.appName}});
  }
  if (this.createServer) {
    this.invoke("blog:server", {options: {nested: true, appName: this.appName}});
  }
};
```

In client\index.js:

```
var BlogGenerator = module.exports = function BlogGenerator(args, options, config) {
  var that = this;
  yeoman.Base.apply(this, arguments);
  // in this.options we have the object passed to 'invoke' in app/index.js:
  this.appName = that.options.appName;
  this.nested  = that.options.nested;
};

BlogGenerator .prototype.askFor = function askFor() {
  var cb = this.async();

  if (!this.options.nested) {
    console.log(this.yeoman);
  }
}
```

**UPDATE 2015-12-21**:
Using `invoke` is deprecated now and should be replaced with `composeWith`. But it's not as easy as it could be. The main difference between `invoke` and `composeWith` is that now you have no ability to control subgenerators. You could only declare using them.
Here's how `main` method from above should look like:

```
BlogGenerator.prototype.main = function app() {
  if (this.createClient) {
    this.composeWith("blog:client", { 
        options: { 
          nested: true, 
          appName: this.appName
        } 
      }, {
        local: require.resolve("./../client")
      });
  }
  if (this.createServer) {
    this.composeWith("blog:server", { 
        options: { 
          nested: true, 
          appName: this.appName
        } 
      }, {
        local: require.resolve("./../server")
      });
  }
};
```

Also I removed replaced `yeoman.generators.Base` with `yeoman.Base`.

Comment: I know this is old, but it's close to what I'm looking for. My problem is that my subgenerator extends "yeoman.generators.NamedBase". When I run this code, I get "Error: Did not provide required argument name!" I'm trying to figure out how to also pass the name (i.e. "test" in "yo make:controller test") to the subgenerators called by .invoke(). Any help?

Comment: Got it: this.invoke("make:controller", {options: {nested: true, ...}, args: [this.name] });

Comment: if you are getting this error "Did not provide required argument name yeoman" -- with composeWith. Just change yeoman.generators.NamedBase to yeoman.generators.Base

https://github.com/yeoman/generator/issues/521

Answer (score 8):

2015-04 update: The yeoman api now includes `this.composeWith` as the preferred method for linking generators.

docs: http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html

Answer (score 2):

You can cover all possible execution scenarios, condition checking, prompting when composing generators together if you decouple generators and use a 'main-generator' the run context loop will help you. Use the `options` of `.composeWith('my-genertor', { 'options' : options })` for passing configurations to composed generators.

When using `.composeWith` a priority group function (e.g.: `prompting`, `writing`...) will be executed for all the generators, then the next priority group. If you call `.composeWith` to **generatorB** from inside a **generatorA**, then execution will be, e.g.:

> generatorA.prompting => generatorB.prompting => generatorA.writing =>
>   generatorB.writing

If you want to control execution between different generators, I advise you to create a "main" generator which composes them together, like written on http://yeoman.io/authoring/composability.html#order:

```js
// In my-generator/generators/turbo/index.js
module.exports = require('yeoman-generator').Base.extend({
  'prompting' : function () {
    console.log('prompting - turbo');
  },

  'writing' : function () {
    console.log('prompting - turbo');
  }
});

// In my-generator/generators/electric/index.js
module.exports = require('yeoman-generator').Base.extend({
  'prompting' : function () {
    console.log('prompting - zap');
  },

  'writing' : function () {
    console.log('writing - zap');
  }
});

// In my-generator/generators/app/index.js
module.exports = require('yeoman-generator').Base.extend({
  'initializing' : function () {
    this.composeWith('my-generator:turbo');
    this.composeWith('my-generator:electric');
  }
});
```