# Grunt.js and folder iteration + options per folder

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I'm looking if its possible when using grunt to build a task that would use my folder structure to build data.

I wanted to build a website from folder structure.

For example I have:

```
- data
-- folder_n
--- options.json
--- webpagetext.txt
--- additional.html
```

etc.

Then generate my webpage also in folder structure (`folder_n/{variable_as_friendly_url}.html`)

Is it possible to do with grunt? I read most of docs, but did not find if that would be possible.

Edit: How would I see it in PHP

```
<?php
/*
    Basic project structure

    templates/
    - template_1.php
    - template_2.php
    - template_3.php
    datafeed/
    - subpage_1/
    -- header_image.png
    -- webpagetext.txt
    -- options.json
    - subpage_2/
    -- header_image.png
    -- webpagetext.txt
    -- options.json
    - subpage_3/
    -- header_image.png
    -- webpagetext.txt
    -- options.json
    - subpage_n/
    -- header_image.png
    -- webpagetext.txt
    -- options.json

*/

// IN PHP it would look like.

foreach (glob('datafeed/*') as $dir){
    foreach(glob('templates/*') as $tpl){
        constructpage($dir, $tpl);
    }
}

function constructpage($dir, $tpl) {
    $options = json_decode($dir.'options.json');
    $output_html_file_name = 'output/'.basename($dir) . '/' . basename($dir) . '.html';
    /*
        Logic that would copy, assign vars etc for template in $tpl.
    */

}
```

But grunt is my choice because of: I want to learn it, it got some pretty cool tools.

Comment: trying to understand: you would like to create a website boilerplate, to create new websites quickly and automatically, using Gruntjs?

Comment: More like create ready articles (subpages) for sites from data in files.
For example: one folder is article. It can use one of 3 templates and those are parsed with options.
PHP without php. Want to have already generated "cache" files to be served. Not sure if you get my point

Comment: I think what you need are Yeoman sub-generators

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a **[Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generator/sub-generator**

---

WHAT IT IS:

> According to the [Yeoman website](http://yeoman.io/), generator is basically a plugin that can be run with the `yo` command to scaffold complete projects or useful parts

---

WHAT IT CAN DO

You can run Yeoman commands from the command line; Yeoman is able to acommodate the code it creates and adapt it to the parameters you provide, or which are present in your files.

---

DOCUMENTATION

For more information about Yeoman scaffolding:

[Yeoman official tutorial](http://yeoman.io/learning/)

[Call sub-generators with user-supplied arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20721060/yeoman-call-sub-generator-with-user-supplied-arguments)

---

FOR (STILL) MORE AUTOMATION

Also, although I still only have a partial understanding of what you really mean to achieve, you might want to trigger the creation of files by Yeoman, when some file directory exists, by using a Grunt watch like so:

```
watch: {
  scripts: {
    files: ['**/*.file-directory-to-detect'],
    tasks: ['myCustomYeomanScript'],
  },
}
```

and [grunt-shell](https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell) like so:

```
grunt.initConfig({
shell: {
    myCustomYeomanScript: {
        command: 'yo createMyFiles'
    }
}
```

});

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer. I updated question making a prototype workflow of script in PHP. Maybe it would help to understand me.
Not sure if Yeoman is for this. Yeoman from what I understood is designed to create ready code for big sites. Not small subpages.
Also it totally is not going to use javascript, and css would be inline (it's strange but I know what im doing :) ).
PS: Im still digging into yeoman docs meanwhile.

Comment: Yes, Yeoman can scaffold anything, big or small, and any file type too, whatever the language. 100% configurable

Comment: You are welcome. I know Yeoman can seem complex, or not enough documented; but just follow the tutorial, observe what files are created, how to structure the model templates, and you will soon be able to customize your scaffolding to your liking: you could easily have Yeoman create PHP files; afterword: not affiliated to Yeoman, but I like the tool

Comment: Hey, I did. Ended up writing my own scripts. Found ``Yo`` a bit too advanced for things I want to do. But answer is good... but not sure how I should chose best answer... the one that is better (your), or the one that solves my problem best (mine).

Comment: life can be hard, sometimes :)